# I need to add search-bar in navigation toolbar for website

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on project and using material-ui@next i.e v1.x.So, which dependencies I need to install.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already installed material-ui@next so you no need to install any other modules. You can acheieve search bar with material-UI Autosuggest component. Check the below link
https://material-ui-next.com/demos/autocomplete/